# Couldn't connect to webservice over remote with php script

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Im trying to connect webservice over remote server by running php script locally. I am reading the entire file, it displays none. When I tried this url in my browser, it fetches the data. I changed my test php file with permissions to 755 and enabled allow_url_fopen,php_openssl.dll. Any suggestions would be appreciated

**My code here:**

$url = 'http://mail.abc.com:10139/webservices2.0.asmx?WSDL';

echo  file_get_contents($url);

---

I get an error as couldnt connect to host when I tried to call soap over remote server. Any suggestions?

Code here:

```
    <?php


            ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
                      ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

                       $url="http://mail.abc.com:10139/webservices2.0.asmx?WSDL";

                   $client  = new  SoapClient ( null , array ( 'location'  =>  "http://mail.abc.com:10139/webservices2.0.asmx?WSDL" , 
                                             'uri'       =>  "http://mail.abc.com:10139/webservices2.0/" )) ;
   //echo file_get_contents($url); //Unable to read from url 

        $operator="xxxx";
        $operatorPassword="yyyy";
        $companyId="abc";
        $companyPassword=" ";
        $languageCode="";

        try
        {
            $response =$client->__soapCall("logon,array('Operator' => $operator, 'OperatorPassword' => $operatorPassword, 'CompanyId'=> $companyId, 'CompanyPassword' => $companyPassword, 'LanguageCode' => $languageCode));
        print_r($response);
        }
        catch (SoapFault $result) {
            echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result); 
         echo "</pre>";
        }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get an error when I try to access the page, are you sure it works?

Anyway, I would recommend this code to work with:

```
function get_data($url) {

$ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$variablee = get_data('http://example.com');
echo $variablee;
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I would try it and get back to you.

Comment: I tried the above code, it's not accepting my url of ERP application in remote server but works well with other urls. Is there any wrong on my side or server applications@Daniel Chernenkov

Comment: @user2345099 you running this code on your own server so you need to use the local address. It can be '127.0.0.1' OR 'localhost'

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked to me. wrong with my port in local server@Daniel Chernenkov

Comment: @user2345099 I will be thankful if you will vote up this answer and mark this answer correct. happy to help you!

Comment: Done it.Thank you very much. @Daniel Chernenkov